# How Tor sites are made, without javascript?

Tags: website

Hello i would like to know what technology is used to make a tor site, i successfully create a tor site just a single page using html, ccs and javascript, but for security reasons many users disable javascript for the client side, so is not possible to use react or vue to create tor sites?, only can run server side request for example php django? i am bit of confuse, what major technology is used for tor sites? what about blazor .Net sites? Thanks

Comment: you just... don't use javascript? why is it confusing?

Answer (score 2):

Good time of the day! The technologies used are **exactly** the same as for the regular websites, because Tor is just a port forwarding proxy for a web server. However - the good case to make a website is to make it really static, so you can use engines like:

- Next.JS
- Jekyll

... check the full list here https://jamstack.org/generators/